# String.includes doesn't find substring

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have the following text:

```
 LOG: time="2021-12-09T16:55:25+01:00" level=debug msg="  GetLatestBlock called" blockHeight=3 blockID=ee98016d268630db54b814d18d0127edac8cc36f90d193c0c6f5fd4909bbd8b1
    ,LOG: time="2021-12-09T16:55:25+01:00" level=debug msg="  GetAccountAtLatestBlock called" address=f8d6e0586b0a20c7
    ,LOG: time="2021-12-09T16:55:26+01:00" level=debug msg="️✉️   Transaction submitted" txID=5a46897e60f13ee68e11ef754983fefe9ec7bc8a2ca6079f0665e404138735e9
    ,LOG: time="2021-12-09T16:55:26+01:00" level=info msg="⭐  Transaction executed" computationUsed=6 txID=5a46897e60f13ee68e11ef754983fefe9ec7bc8a2ca6079f0665e404138735e9
    ,LOG: time="2021-12-09T16:55:26+01:00" level=debug msg="\x1b[1;34mLOG\x1b[0m \x1b[2m[5a4689]\x1b[0m \"Hello from Emulator\""
    time="2021-12-09T16:55:26+01:00" level=debug msg="\x1b[1;34mLOG\x1b[0m \x1b[2m[5a4689]\x1b[0m 0x1cf0e2f2f715450"
    time="2021-12-09T16:55:26+01:00" level=debug msg="\x1b[1;34mLOG\x1b[0m \x1b[2m[5a4689]\x1b[0m 0x179b6b1cb6755e31"
    time="2021-12-09T16:55:26+01:00" level=debug msg="  Block #4 committed" blockHeight=4 blockID=5fd780a98baad6d30f66cf75e76c3e1c9398097a9bb2e3f239f0cd7e166f6932
    ,LOG: time="2021-12-09T16:55:26+01:00" level=debug msg="  GetTransactionResult called" txID=5a46897e60f13ee68e11ef754983fefe9ec7bc8a2ca6079f0665e404138735e9
```

stored in a variable called `transactionLogs` (, so the output you see is `console.log(transactionLogs)`), which is a string.

I want to check if the transaction logs contain two addresses. One from Alice `0x01cf0e2f2f715450` and one from Bob `0x179b6b1cb6755e31`.

My problem is that when I call `includes` like this (where `Alice` and `Bob` are strings):

```
Alice; // 0x01cf0e2f2f715450
Bob; // 0x179b6b1cb6755e31
transactionLogs.includes(Alice); // false
transactionLogs.includes(Bob); // true
```

the search for Alice returns `false`.

I assume it has something to do with escape backslashes, so I tried running `transactionLogs.replace(String.fromCharCode(92), '')` but that doesn't change the result.

What is going on here? Why is `includes` not returning `true` for Alice?

Comment: The Id that you have mentioned for Alice i.e, 0x01cf0e2f2f715450 is not present in the log, is it?

Comment: I can't find 0x01cf0e2f2f715450 in your text, I see only a 0x1cf0e2f2f715450 (notice the missing 0)

Comment: Deepack is correct: the log contains `0x1cf...`, so searching for `0x01cf...` will not work.

Comment: `Alice` seems to be `0x1cf0e2f2f715450` while you're looking for `0x01cf0e2f2f715450`. Perhaps there is something wrong in whatever is either logging `0x01cf0e2f2f715450` or returing `0x1cf0e2f2f715450`?

Comment: maybe you can `transactionLogs.includes(parseInt(Alice, 16).toString(16))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is includes not returning `true` for Alice?

Because that string is not present in the log string:

```js
const transactionLogs = `
 LOG: time="2021-12-09T16:55:25+01:00" level=debug msg="  GetLatestBlock called" blockHeight=3 blockID=ee98016d268630db54b814d18d0127edac8cc36f90d193c0c6f5fd4909bbd8b1
    ,LOG: time="2021-12-09T16:55:25+01:00" level=debug msg="  GetAccountAtLatestBlock called" address=f8d6e0586b0a20c7
    ,LOG: time="2021-12-09T16:55:26+01:00" level=debug msg="️✉️   Transaction submitted" txID=5a46897e60f13ee68e11ef754983fefe9ec7bc8a2ca6079f0665e404138735e9
    ,LOG: time="2021-12-09T16:55:26+01:00" level=info msg="⭐  Transaction executed" computationUsed=6 txID=5a46897e60f13ee68e11ef754983fefe9ec7bc8a2ca6079f0665e404138735e9
    ,LOG: time="2021-12-09T16:55:26+01:00" level=debug msg="\x1b[1;34mLOG\x1b[0m \x1b[2m[5a4689]\x1b[0m \"Hello from Emulator\""
    time="2021-12-09T16:55:26+01:00" level=debug msg="\x1b[1;34mLOG\x1b[0m \x1b[2m[5a4689]\x1b[0m 0x1cf0e2f2f715450"
    time="2021-12-09T16:55:26+01:00" level=debug msg="\x1b[1;34mLOG\x1b[0m \x1b[2m[5a4689]\x1b[0m 0x179b6b1cb6755e31"
    time="2021-12-09T16:55:26+01:00" level=debug msg="  Block #4 committed" blockHeight=4 blockID=5fd780a98baad6d30f66cf75e76c3e1c9398097a9bb2e3f239f0cd7e166f6932
    ,LOG: time="2021-12-09T16:55:26+01:00" level=debug msg="  GetTransactionResult called" txID=5a46897e60f13ee68e11ef754983fefe9ec7bc8a2ca6079f0665e404138735e9
`;

const Alice = `0x01cf0e2f2f715450`;
const Bob = `0x179b6b1cb6755e31`;

console.log({
  Alice: transactionLogs.includes(Alice),
  Bob: transactionLogs.includes(Bob),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are searching for an hex address that is printed wrongly in the transaction log.

I think you should change the *transaction log* logic to avoid to cut the leading 0 in the addresses when logging.

Otherwise you have to remove the leading zeros from the address you are searching for, ie with

```
transactionLog.includes('0x' + parseInt(Alice, 16).toString(16))
```